# NameError: name 'line' is not defined. Did you mean: 'slice'?

Tags: python

So when I include the block that shows the lines I need read for the avg_max, avg_min, and avg_avg, I get the error in the title.  When I completely remove this block of code, it prints out everything perfectly fine, but it just shows a 0.0 average for all 3 temperatures.  How am I able to get my code to read the proper lines to be able to get the numbers it needs to get the average?  Here is my code below so far:

```
my_file = open("PIT_Temps.txt","r")

avg_max = 0
avg_min = 0
avg_avg = 0


all_lines = my_file.readlines()

avg_max = avg_max + int(line[9:11])
avg_min = avg_min + int(line[12:14])
avg_avg = avg_avg + int(line[15:17])

for line in all_lines:
    parts = line.split(" ")
    avg_max = avg_max + int(parts[1])
    avg_min = avg_min + int(parts[2])
    avg_avg = avg_avg + int(parts[3])

avg_max = avg_max / len(all_lines)
avg_min = avg_min / len(all_lines)
avg_avg = avg_avg / len(all_lines)

my_file.close()
print('The average temperatures during 8th month of 2015 are:')
print('Daily maximum average: ', avg_max)
print('Daily minimum average: ', avg_min)
print('Daily average average: ', avg_avg)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rkiss\OneDrive\Desktop\temp_lab.py", line 17, in 
<module>
avg_max = avg_max + int(line[9:11])
NameError: name 'line' is not defined. Did you mean: 'slice'?
```

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback (that is, the entire error message starting from the word `Traceback`).

Comment: The code is calling ```line``` before defining it. ```avg_max = avg_max + int(line[9:11])```, but no ```line``` is defined before.

Answer (score 0):

You used the `line` variable before `for line in all_lines:`. You can't use variables before they have been declared.

Comment: Thanks!  It works properly now when I moved that block under the "for line in all_lines".  Unfortunately, the averages of the temperatures are slightly off.  Is there a reason why this would be?